# Error messages or Success Redirection not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this form that is supposed to send the user information to another file build in php that processes it and then decides to show an error if there are errors or decides to redirect to the `success.php` page, but the errors don't show per each field if they are caused or the redirection in cases of success doesn't show!

```
<form action="dive-activity-photos/photos.php" class="contact-one__form contact-form-validated" novalidate="novalidate" id="book-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full name"
                    name="name" id="name" required maxlength="50">
                <div class="error-message" data-input="name"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address"
                    name="email" id="email" required maxlength="100">
                <div class="error-message" data-input="email"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                    name="phone" id="phone" required maxlength="20">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label for="diver-status">Diver Status:</label>
            <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="diver-status" tabindex="-98" id="diver-status"
                    required>
                    <option value="">Select your diver status</option>
                    <option value="licensed">Licensed Diver</option>
                    <option value="unlicensed">Unlicensed Diver</option>
                    <option value="no-experience">Licensed Diver with no experience</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label for="participation-type">Participation Type:</label>
            <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="participation-type" tabindex="-98"
                    id="participation-type" required>
                    <option value="">Select your participation type</option>
                    <option value="one-dive">One Dive</option>
                    <option value="two-dives">Two Dives</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label for="service-select">Diving Option:</label>
            <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="diving-option" tabindex="-98" id="service-select"
                    required>
                    <option value="">Select your diving option</option>
                    <option value="private">Private Diving</option>
                    <option value="group">Group Diving (Join a Random Group)</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" required>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Time:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="time"
                    value="defined automatically" required readonly>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="6" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter your message" maxlength="200" required></textarea>
                <span id="message-counter"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="error-message" data-input="message"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="form-errors" class="error" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="form-errors" class="error" style="display: none;"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="thm-btn contact-one__btn" style="width:100%">Send
                message</button>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
    </div>

</form>


$(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

                // Serialize form data
                var formData = $(this).serialize();

                // Send AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'dive-activity-photos/photos.php',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
                            // Handle form validation errors
                            var errorMessages = '';
                            $.each(response.errors, function (field, message) {
                                errorMessages += message + '\n';
                            });
                            alert(errorMessages);
                        } else {
                            // Check if the insertion was successful
                            if (response.hasOwnProperty('inserted') && response.inserted == true) {
                                // Redirect to success page
                                window.location.href = 'success.php';
                            } else {
                                // Handle insertion error
                                alert('An error occurred while inserting data into the database.');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        // Handle AJAX error
                        alert('An error occurred while submitting the form.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This is the other page that is supposed to get the redirection done

```
<?php
include "database.php";
 
function isWithinLimit($value, $maxLength)
{
    return mb_strlen($value) <= $maxLength;
}

$errors = [];
 
$fields = [
    'name' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Name is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'email' => [
        'max_length' => 200,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Email is required and must be within 200 characters.'
    ],
    'phone' => [
        'max_length' => 20,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Phone is required and must be within 20 characters.'
    ],
    'diver-status' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Diver status is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'participation-type' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Participation type is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'diving-option' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Diving option is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'date' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Date is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'time' => [
        'max_length' => 50,
        'required' => true,
        'error_message' => 'Time is required and must be within 50 characters.'
    ],
    'message' => [
        'max_length' => 200,
        'required' => false,
        'error_message' => 'Message must be within 200 characters.'
    ],
];

foreach ($fields as $field => $options) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        $sanitizedValue = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if (!isWithinLimit($sanitizedValue, $options['max_length'])) {
            $errors[$field] = $options['error_message'];
        }

        $_POST[$field] = $sanitizedValue;
    } else if ($options['required']) {
        $errors[$field] = $options['error_message'];
    }
}

 
if (!empty($errors)) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($errors as $error) { ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
  
    $rand = rand();
    $ref_no = date('s') * (date('H') + 1) + 3 + 10 + $rand;

    // Insert data into the database
    try {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations (name, email, phone, diver_status, participation_type, diving_option, date, time, message, status, ref_no) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'pending', ?)");
        // Bind the form data and reference number to the prepared statement parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['phone']);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['diver-status']);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['participation-type']);
        $stmt->bindParam(6, $_POST['diving-option']);
        $stmt->bindParam(7, $_POST['date']);
        $stmt->bindParam(8, $_POST['time']);
        $stmt->bindParam(9, $_POST['message']);
        $stmt->bindParam(10, $ref_no);

    
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location: success.php');
  
        $conn = null;

       
     
        exit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Database error']);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 'the errors dont show per each field if they are caused or the redirection in cases of success doesnt show' - so what does happen when you submit the form?  What do you see?  Have you checked the PHP error log?

Comment: While testing the form, I noticed that the error message does not display when the 'required' attribute is intentionally removed from an input field using the inspect element tool. This issue should be addressed to ensure proper error handling and validation for users.

Comment: I tried adjusting this jquery code but it causes duplication in the database and even after the insert query works in php code it shows error for no reason :

Comment: Put this information into the QUESTION, using the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76209438/edit) link